# question regarding the insertion of records by using SOAP api

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices

I have included the code below for the insertion of account, contact & opportunity records

As per the code I think I can insert single contact at a time, if another system move multiple accounts to sfdc at that time i want to change any code. to insert multiple accounts

```
 global class Integration {

     global class AllObjects {

         webservice string aName;
         webservice string aNum;

         webservice string cName
     }

     global class Return {
         webservice string raName;
     }

     webservice static Return Allobjectsmethod(AllObjects a1) {
         Account a = new Account();
         a.Name = a1.aName;
         a.Number = a1.aNum;
         insert a;

         Contact c = new Contact();
         c.Name = a1.cName;
         insert c;

         Return r = new Return();
         r.raName = a.Name;
         return r;

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what your asking is how to change the code to accept a list of AllObject's?

```
webservice static List<Return> Allobjectsmethod(List<AllObjects> a1)
```

To implement this method you need to ensure you minimise the number 'insert' statements (known as DML statements) you execute as Apex governors the [maximum per request to 100](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm). Fortunately this statement allows you to pass a list of records to insert, this practice btw is known as '[bulkifciation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_limits_tips.htm)' on the Force.com platform. So you can adapt your code to something like this...

```
webservice static List<Return> Allobjectsmethod(List<AllObjects> a1List) {

     List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
     List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
     List<Return> returns = new List<Return);
     for(AllObjects a1 : a1List)
     {
         Account a = new Account();
         a.Name = a1.aName;
         a.Number = a1.aNum;
         accounts.add(a);
         Contact c = new Contact();
         c.Name = a1.cName;
         contacts.add(c);
         Return r = new Return();
         r.raName = a.Name;
         results.add(r);
     }

     // Bulk insert accounts
     insert accounts;

     // Assign contacts to accounts
     for(Integer rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < accounts.size(); rowIdx++)
         contacts[rowIdx].AccountId = accounts[rowIdx].Id;      

     // Bulk insert contacts
     insert contacts;

     return returns;
 }
```

I noticed in your sample code you don't associate the contacts with the accounts created, i assume this was just an omission to keep your question short. If not, make sure once you have inserted the Accounts you loop back over your Contacts and associate them before inserting the contacts.

**Update:** I've updated the sample code to show the association between Account and Contact being made.

**NOTE:** Its also worth noting that Salesforce does provide a number of existing web service and REST API's to plainly insert records into its objects. The benefit however of your approach here is there will be a database transaction boundary around your Apex Web Service. Meaning if any of your contacts fail to insert, it will rollback any of the Accounts as well.

Comment: May i know how can i test my class for bulk insertion or not.

Comment: from my above webservice hoe can map account id to contact.and where can i replace my code for this.

Comment: As per my note, you need to insert the accounts then loop back over the contacts assigning the AccountId field on the Contact accordingly.

Comment: Andrew Fawcett Hi i modigy like this c.AccountId = a.Id; but it is not inserting can you modify my code where i have to asign accountid to contact.

Comment: I've added some more code to illustrate this, however you really perhaps should take time to study the Apex Developers guide more on writing tests and general coding, you will find your investment worth while in the future! ;-)

Comment: Thanq For Updating my code how can i prevent duplicates that means if same account name comes from third party  second time means in sfdc it have to check account is exist or not if exist means under that account new contact have to be crated how can i achieve this.

Comment: You will have to query for duplicates using SOQL before attempting to insert new contacts. The scope of this answer and the space here does not really allow us to go into further detail and what your asking is really something you will learn from getting better at programming in Apex generally. However if your still struggling please feel free to form a new question on StackExchange for further advice. I think for now, this question and answer should be completed.

Comment: once check it   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/account-duplication

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11888/discussion-between-sathya-and-andrew-fawcett)

Comment: when i use for loop to asign a contact to account first time it is inserting again if same account comes means it showing an error how can i solve this error Is--System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0